# PHP fuzzer for security checking (Radamsa)

Tags: php, fuzzer

Does anyone know a good fuzzer for checking PHP security? I am using a Mac and just installed the Radamsa fuzzer from [git](https://github.com/aoh/radamsa) but I don't know how to use it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you read [its documentation](https://github.com/aoh/radamsa/blob/master/README.md)?

Answer (score 2):

I guess if you are interested in fuzzing PHP itself you should check out http://php-security.org/2010/05/11/mops-submission-05-the-minerva-php-fuzzer/ for starters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer wintermute! I'll check it out!